# replacing value in xml file using sed value from variable missing ""s

Tags: linux, sed, xml

hi can some one please help me here
i am trying to replace value in tomcat server.xml file **username** using sed command

```
<Resource username="user1" password="xxxxxxxx"/>
```

below command  replacing value as expected but missing "" around value as i am taking value from variable U.

```
export U="userx"
sed -i -E  's/(username=)([a-zA-Z0-9"-])+/\1'"$U"'/g' server.xml
```

output missing "" around userx :   `<Resource username=userx password="xxxxxxxx"/>`

if i use value instead of variable its working with "" as well

```
sed -i -E  's/(username=)([a-zA-Z0-9"-])+/\1"userx"/g' server.xml

ouput: <Resource username="userx" password="xxxxxxxx"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing XML with `sed` can be prone to failure. Use an XML editing tool instead. For example, with `xmlstarlet` it becomes trivial

```
U='userx'
xmlstarlet edit --inplace --update '//Resource/@username' --value "$U" server.xml
```

Personally, I wouldn't use `--inplace` until I'd finished testing that the replacement worked.

`xmlstarlet` is commonly available from your distribution's package manager. If you don't have it and don't have the rights to install it, submit a request to your Change Board to do so. It's about using the right tool for the right job.

---

Incidentally, the reason your `sed` command didn't work is because it never saw the double quotes you wanted to include. Here's your original command with some annotation

> ```
> sed -E 's/(username=)([a-zA-Z0-9"-])+/\1'"$U"'/g'
>        ^single quotes start             ^single quotes end
>                                          ^double quotes start
>                                             ^double quotes end
> ```

The shell uses quotes to identify how to parse strings (or not). The single quotes provide a literal sequence of characters. Double quotes protect most characters but specifically allow variables to be evaluated. *The command (`sed` in this instance) never sees these outer quotes.* So to include double quotes in your string you need to quote them.

For readability *but not syntactic accuracy* I have split the corrected single expression at quotes

```
sed -E 's/(username=")([a-zA-Z0-9-])+/\1' "$U" '"/g'
       ^literal text used as an RE
                                          ^variable (quoted to protect it from the shell)
                                               ^more literal text
```

Putting this together again so that `sed` sees a single expression string,

```
sed -E 's/(username=")([a-zA-Z0-9-])+/\1'"$U"'"/g'
```

Comment: thanks for your help,  yes it's working fine and much easier the sed command,  as I have multiple xml files to edit, and this suits to fix all my issues  :).  thanks once again for quick help